# Is it possible to define CXXFLAGS with respect to the current compiler in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to convert a Make project to Bazel. Currently, makefile detects the compiler being used and sets certain CXXFLAGS accordingly (not all flags are understood by all compilers).

For example:

```
ifeq ($(shell $(CC) -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep __clang__),)
CXXFLAGS=-DUSE_GCC
else
CXXFLAGS=-DUSE_CLANG
endif
```

(Similarly code for compiler versions.)

How can I achieve this in bazel? The relation between a compiler and the flags to be used should be defined somewhere within the project (not on the commandline).

I know the --define option, but is there a way to directly relate the configration to the compiler being used?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `copts` argument in your cc_library or cc_binary will set compiler flags.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary_args